# Is there any way to categorise Firebase events?

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

I have created a lot of events for my app and now it's a bit of a chaos in my Firebase Analytics dashboard. Is there any way, that you could categorise events inside Firebase?

Comment: Do you mean the Firebase Analytics events?

Comment: Yes, that's true, my bad.